# Why can't I assign a boolean operator to a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

If I try something like `bool_op = and`, it returns a syntax error.

Even if I try:

```
def bool_op():
    and
```

that also returns a syntax error.

Is there any way I can create a shorthand for some boolean operations, such as `bool_and = and`, `bool_or = or` and `bool_xor = (not and) and (or)` and be able to use them as operations?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Take a look at the [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module in the standard library.

Comment: @Doc Initially I wanted to create a shorthand for the `xor` logical operator, until I found out that `a != b` is the same as `xor`.